# Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version 4.0.30319.225 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime

Tags: 2010, feature-activation

So, the story is the following:

I just joined a team of an existing sharepoint project, sharepoint is installed RTM on all environments, from DEV to production.

But because its 2 companies working for the same project, Me as a member of the 2nd company, my VM has .net framework 4.0 already installed.

So I was in charge of making some changes adding fields, features, etc.

And when I was going to use Enable-SP Feature I had this exception:
I have 2 options so far:

1. Install SP1, and the June CU in all environments.
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536599
2. Uninstall .net 4 from my environment.
3. Here comes, the question, is there another way to solve it?

**Update1:**
by checking the logs I found more info:

> A PlatformNotSupportedException occured while trying to acquire the
>   local farm: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft SharePoint
>   is not supported with version 4.0.30319.225 of the Microsoft .Net
>   Runtime.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.get_Farm()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm.FindLocal(SPFarm& farm,
>   Boolean& isJoined)

Comment: I checked and all the projects inside the solution are .net 3.5

Comment: i have the same error but not using powergui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is a PowerGUI issue, you can fix it by following [this solution](http://ybbest.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/how-to-fix-microsoft-sharepoint-is-not-supported-with-version-4-0-30319-225-of-the-microsoft-net-runtime-in-powergui/). Follow these steps.

1. Open your windows explorer and navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerGUI\ and open the configuration file ScriptEditor.exe.config.
2. Change the supportedRuntime version under Startup settings by removing the version=”v4.0″ as below

Final `<Startup>` element

```
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
           <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    </startup>
```

Now you can enjoy the powerful editor again.

If you check the startup settings and the version is v2.0.50727, try closing PowerGUI and reopening.

Comment: I don't use PowerGUI. I have this error in PowerShell command like this Restore-SPSite server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak, what i must do?
PS Sorry for my bed English, i'm a Russian :(

Comment: I was having this issue without PowerGUI as well but this solution gave me the hint to fix the issue.  Simply launch powershell 2.0 instead of 4.0 from an administrative command prompt, like so `powershell -version 2.0` (to add the sharepoint commands, run `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` of course!).

Answer (score 4):

If you dont use powerGUI but use `powershell.exe`:

1. Go to:

   ```
   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
   ```
2. Find:

   ```
   powershell_ise.exe.config
   ```
3. Change:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   <configuration> 
       <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
           <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />    
       </startup> 
   </configuration>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
   <configuration> 
       <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
           <supportedRuntime version="v2.0" />    
       </startup> 
   </configuration>
   ```
4. Save the file and it will work fine.

There is no need to change `powershell.exe` to

```
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -Version 2. -NoExit " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\\sharepoint.ps1 '
```

That won't work if you want to run as admin, my simple solution above works just fine and should be the correct way!

It is similar to Fruqan's solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I partially found the error.

POWERGUI tool is the guilty one, when I run the upgrade spsolution and install sp feature in the normal powershell window it works. In powerGUI it does not work.